# Gravitational potential when $n \geq 2$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, planets

The standard gravitational potential given by Newton is $V(r) = \frac{k}{r}$. What happens when $V(r) = \frac{k}{r^2}$ and when $V(r) = \frac{k}{r^n}$ with $n \geq 2$? Does it matters if $n$ is odd or even?

Comment: Well, then it isn't the gravitational potential.

Comment: If I recall (and I'm pretty hazy on this), its provable that the only forms of that equation which conserve energy in a flat Euclidean space are n=1 and n=2.

Comment: For $n\ge2$, the gravitational field will no longer have a zero divergence, so it won't satisfy Gauss's law.

Comment: @CortAmmon Any time-independent potential will conserve energy. Perhaps you are thinking of [Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem), which says that only for $n=1$ and $n=-2$ are the bound orbits also closed orbits (for $n=1 that happens because of the Runge-Lenz vector).

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for setting me straight!  That's definitely the theorem I was thinking of!

Answer (score 2):

$V(r)=kr^{-n}$ decreases more rapidly with increasing $r$ as $n$ gets larger: this force becomes less of a long-range force than gravity or electromagnetism is. It is still a conservative central force, angular momentum conservation still remains. The oddness or evenness does not have any effect (were $n$ the result of different dimensionality of space, then the evenness of the number of dimensions would affect how solutions of the wave equation behave, but not this force).

Combined with centrifugal force the effective potential becomes $$U(r)=kr^{-n}+ \frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2}.$$ If $k<0$ bound orbits are possible. A circular orbit is given by $U'(r)=0$, or $-nkr^{-n-1}-\frac{L^2}{ \mu r^3}=0$, or $r=(-L^2/nk\mu)^{1/(2-n)}$. Note that $n=2$ is a special case where there are no bounded orbits. [Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem) states that bound orbits do not close for $n>1$: they will precess.

Comment: Also worth noting:  circular orbits are unstable for $n > 2$.  You could in principle set up an object in a circular orbit in such a potential, but the slightest nudge would cause it to either spiral in to the center or fly off to infinity.  This can be shown by looking at the second derivative of the effective potential.